# grep for x but exclude y and z

Tags: bash, unix, syntax, grep

Trying to search for a specific term but exclude longer matching terms from a directory full of files.

I want to find all lines matching "ge-"
But exclude lines matching "ge-0/0/0", "ge-0/0/46" and "ge-0/0/47".

I tried a simple version of this just to get it working and it doesn't remove what I'm asking it to. It just gives me all lines matching "ge-" without removing lines matching the above mentioned.

```
grep -v "ge-0/0/0" | grep -r "ge-" > r.xls
```

If I try to search the directory for x and filter out y after, it just fills the output file with a bunch of wild data.

```
grep -r "ge-" | grep -v "ge-0/0/0" > r.xls
```

Example:

```
r.xls:r.xls:r.xls:r.xls:r.xls:r.xls:r.xls:1798-:  vlan2             80:d7:33:5b:9e:98 Learn          0 ge-0/0/20.0
r.xls:r.xls:r.xls:r.xls:r.xls:r.xls:r.xls:1622-:  vlan2             80:d7:33:5b:b2:f7 Learn          0 ge-0/0/24.0
```

I've tried many more "solutions" that all seem to net the same result:

```
grep -r "ge-" > r.xls | grep -v "ge-0/0/0|ge-0/0/46|ge-0/0/47" r.xls  > results.xls
```

and

```
grep -v "ge-0/0/0" | grep -v "ge-0/0/46" | grep -v "ge-0/0/47" | grep -r "ge-" > r.xls
```

and

```
grep -Fv "ge-0/0/0" | grep -Fv "ge-0/0/46" | grep -Fv "ge-0/0/47" | grep -r "ge-" > r.xls
```

all produce the same output as the first solution I tried.

This is a sample of the output:

```
1669-:  vlan2             80:d7:33:5b:ab:e7 Learn          0 ge-0/0/22.0
1039-:  vlan2             80:d7:33:5b:ad:4f Learn          0 ge-0/0/47.0
1039-:  vlan2             80:d7:33:5b:ad:71 Learn          0 ge-0/0/47.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `grep -r` or `grep ... filename`, then `grep` will ignore stdin and only produce independent, fresh results from the current dir or given filename.

Here's what you should be doing:

```
search | filter | filter | filter > output
```

Here's what you're doing instead in most of your examples. Since the filters don't apply to the search, they're effectively dead, and it's equivalent to just `search > output`.

```
filter | filter | filter | search > output
```

Additionally, you write to a file in the current directory, so `grep -r` will search through the results and add them to the results, which is obviously a bit chaotic.

Given this, here's what you can do instead:

```
# Remove your old result file
rm r.xls   
# Search first, then filter, then write to a file *outside* the current dir
grep -r "ge-" | grep -v "ge-0/0/0" > ../r.xls
```

Comment: Yea I figured it wasn't registering the filters before the search as it didn't have any data to filter, but I just couldn't figure out why I was getting all that extraneous data, which in retrospect makes complete sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
grep -Fr 'ge-' . | grep -vE 'ge-0/0/(0|4[67])'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer while waiting for a reply.
@that other guy also came to the same conclusion.

I needed to output the results of my grep to different directory.
I was navigating to the folder, running grep recursively on those files and saving it to the same directory.

Which has worked for me in the past when I was only doing a single search, and no filtering, when I added the filtering is when I ran into issues.

Here's what I used:

```
grep -r "ge-" | grep -v "ge-0/0/0" | grep -v "ge-0/0/47" | grep -v "ge-0/0/46" > /home/myuser/Results/r.xls
```

Which worked perfectly.

Comment: You don't really multiple `grep -v`. See my answer above to do that in single `grep -v`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find all lines matching "ge-" But exclude lines matching
> "ge-0/0/0", "ge-0/0/46" and "ge-0/0/47".

With `-P` and a negative lookahead `(?!NOTPATTERN)`:

```
grep -r -P 'ge-(?!0/0/0|0/0/46|0/0/47)' .
```